# Codeigniter URI Routing Issue

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following URL

domain.com/name/details/12345

I want it so if someone types in

domain.com/name/12345 it goes to the above

I am using $route[‘name/details/(:num)’] = ‘name/’;

But I get a 404 error when I try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the documentation:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/routing.html

It looks like what you want is:

`$route['name/(:num)'] = 'name/details/$1';`

The route name/12345 is matched and routed to name/details/12345